# The group generated by two homeomorphism $f,g$ is free group?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

In my manuscript, we assume that $F_2=\langle a, b\rangle$ is free group.
Also, we assume that $\varphi:F_2\times X\to X$ is generated by two homeomorphism $\varphi_a=f$ and $\varphi_b=g$.

Referee ask me why  the group generated by two homeomorphism $f, g$ is free group?

What can conditions on $f, g$ to implies that the group generated by two homeomorphism $f, g$ is free group?

Comment: @DerekAllums In my manuscript, I assume that $F_2=\langle a, b\rangle$ be a free group and $\varphi:F_2\times X\to X$ is generated by two homeomorphism $\varphi_a=f$ and $\varphi_b=g$ with $f\circ g\neq id_X$. Referee ask me why the group generated by two homeomorphism $f,g$ is free group?

Comment: The condition $f\circ g\neq id_X$ is far from sufficient. There should be absolutely no relation between $f$ and $g.$ Please revise the definition of a free group.

Comment: Read about the ping-pong argument. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20ping%2Dpong,free%20subgroup%20of%20that%20group.